# HTML in PHP - Newbie

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I´m extremely newbie at PHP and has never worked with it. But I really want to learn....
I have a question. I´m working on a WooCommerce Wordpress site and I have a output with this code:
***Return $priceHTML;***
I want to "design" the output with aline break before each output line and do some text output design - but where do I put that? I think I have tried every place in the code.

The complete code looks like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Electro Child
 *
 * @package electro-child
 */

/**
 * Include all your custom code here
 */
// Modify the returned price to show all of the wholesale prices



add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'my_wwpp_show_other_prices', 100, 2    );
function my_wwpp_show_other_prices( $priceHTML, $product ) {

    // Check the current role
    if( !current_user_can('commaxx') ){return $priceHTML;}

    // Get required Wholesale Suite plugins object first
    $wholesale_prices_object = WWPP_Wholesale_Prices::getInstance();
    $wholesale_roles_object = WWP_Wholesale_Roles::getInstance();

    // Get all wholesale roles
    $wholesale_roles = $wholesale_roles_object->getAllRegisteredWholesaleRoles();

    // Loop through all wholesale roles
    foreach( $wholesale_roles as $k => $wholesale_role ){

        // Get the inputted wholesale price (on the backend)
        $saved_wholesale_price = get_post_meta($product->id, $k . '_wholesale_price', true);

        // If the price exists
        if( $saved_wholesale_price ){

            // Get the price including tax
            $price_with_tax = $wholesale_prices_object- >getProductShopPriceWithTaxingApplied( $product , $saved_wholesale_price );

            // Add it to the result
            $priceHTML .=  $wholesale_role['roleName'] . ": " . $price_with_tax . "<br>\n";

        }
    }

    Return $priceHTML;
}
?>
```

VERY grateful for all help!

Comment: You want to learn PHP and you're starting with Wordpress / WooCommerce? That'll kill your enthusiasm for all things PHP dead in about ooooh, a week?

Comment: try start with small step, wordpress is too high for newbie

Comment: You need to find where the function is called and change the layout around that. Don't do it in a function.

Comment: `foreach(...) { $priceHTML .= ...}` is where you'd make your mods. there's your loop that's building html.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, creating, changing or adding html is nothing different from [string concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) of normal text.

There is things you can do here :

```
// Add it to the result
$priceHTML .=  $wholesale_role['roleName'] . ": " . $price_with_tax . "<br>\n";
```

Changing to :

```
// Add it to the result
$priceHTML .=  "<span style='csshere'>" . $wholesale_role['roleName'] . ":</span> " . $price_with_tax . "<br>\n";
```

Or also at the end,

```
Return $priceHTML;
```

To anything like

```
Return "<div style='some-css;'>" . $priceHTML . "</div>";
```

Note that this is not a good practice to meddle with html directly in functions, especially within a framework. If you're learning PHP you may considere the comments.